# Mark request by GUID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have Custom Filter which marks every request:

```
public class GuidToRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["GuidSessionsId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

I need it for logging user's actions. If http-request is reason of several changes within database then all log lines  have the same GUID and it is easy to read such logs.

I need the same functionality for my rest-full ASP.NET WEB API.

How can I do it without using Session object in WEB API?

UPDATE:
In my mvc part I retrieve guid within custom service like this:

```
 public class LogService 
    {
    private LogRow CreateLogRow()
        {
           var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session["GuidSessionsId"].ToString();
        }
     }
```

I need something like this but for WEB API.

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
public class GuidToWebApiRequestAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Request.Headers.Add("GuidSessionsId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }

 public class LogService 
        {
        private LogRow CreateLogRow()
            {
               var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["GuidSessionsId"].ToString();
            }
         }
```

SOLUTION:
I don't understand what exactly is going on here. I just have found out where exactly my header was stored by investigation HttpConext.Current in DebugMode

```
 public class LogService 
            {
            private LogRow CreateLogRow()
                {
                    string sessionId=null; 
                    var httpRequestMessage = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
                    if (httpRequestMessage != null)
                    {
                        var httpRequestHeaders = httpRequestMessage.Headers;
                        sessionId = httpRequestHeaders.GetValues("X-Request-Guid").Last();
                    }
                }
             }
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Have you got an error? an empty string?

Comment: var guid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Request-Guid"]; //guid is NULL here

Comment: It has to be set in the request not to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add it to the Http header using custom header.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Request-Guid",Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
//or 
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("X-Request-Guid",Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

depending on what you trully want to log.

EDIT :

to get the log you can use:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Request-Guid"].ToString())
```

Comment: Now I get GUID (Within my LogService) in such way: HttpContext.Current.Session["GuidSessionsId"] 
After this I put it in database.
How can I retreive GUID using your approach ?

Comment: Headers are like Session dictionaries so you can use the string indexer.

Comment: It doesn't work because within my LogService class I don't have access to filterContext. Please, see update.

Comment: the X- is not optional, it means you use user-defined header.